# How to implement GRID/TILED Image View with scrolling in BB10

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

I want to implement GRID/TILED Image View where tile images will be drawn on the fly after being downloaded. I want to be able to do pinch/zoom and other touch actions in it. Say, If I pan the view, new tiles will be loaded and drawn on the view fully or partially. I couldn't find a way to do it with any existing UI control. Also those existing UI controls can not be subclassed and do not have any paint()/onDraw method (like view/canvas in android) to override. May be imageView with scrollview can solve the problem. The other option might be using foreign Window. In both cases I am not sure how they can be implemented or how gestures will be handled in those cases.Or if there any other way to do it. Please give me some insights to solve it.

Comment: Do you want to zoom a particular image or whole grid view?

Comment: So you want images to be downloaded from internet then to be displayed, right?

Comment: I want to be able to do pinch/zoom and other touch actions in it.

Comment: okay. Where are the source images? Are they in assets or at some remote place and needs to be downloaded via internet?

Comment: `I want to implement GRID/TILED Image View where tile images will be drawn on the fly after being downloaded.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a CustomImageView that would load image from remote and put that CustomImageView in a ListView with GridListLayout. You can use ListItemProvider class to customize your ListView. I have given code for all necessary classes below.

**//main.qml**

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import my.library 1.0 //Custom library where CustomImageView and our ListProvider resides

Page {
    content: ScrollView {
        gestureHandlers: [
            PinchHandler {
                onPinchUpdated: {
                    scrollView.zoomToPoint(event.midPointX, event.midPointY, event.pinchRatio)
                }
            }
        ]
        id: scrollView
        scrollViewProperties {
            scrollMode: ScrollMode.None
            pinchToZoomEnabled: true
        }
        ListView {
            overlapTouchPolicy: OverlapTouchPolicy.Allow
            objectName: "listView"
            layout: GridListLayout {
                columnCount: 2
            }
            listItemProvider: CustomImageViewProvider { //Our list item provider
            }
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    CustomImageView { //CustomImageView to load image from remote via internet
                    }
                }
            ]
            dataModel: XmlDataModel {
                source: "model/path.xml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**//CustomImageView.cpp** CustomControl to load image form remote location via internet

```
CustomImageView::CustomImageView(Container *parent) :
    CustomControl(parent) {
    Container *contentContainer = new Container();
    DockLayout *contentLayout = new DockLayout();
    contentContainer->setLayout(contentLayout);

    mItemImage = ImageView::create("");
    mItemImage->setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment::Fill);
    mItemImage->setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment::Fill);

    contentContainer->add(mItemImage);

    setRoot(contentContainer);
}

void CustomImageView::updateItem(const QString imagePath) {
    WebServiceRequest *webServiceRequest = new WebServiceRequest(imagePath);
    connect(webServiceRequest, SIGNAL(complete(QByteArray, bool)), this,
            SLOT(onComplete(QByteArray, bool)));
    webServiceRequest->getResponse();
}

void CustomImageView::onComplete(QByteArray data, bool success) {
    if (success) {
        mItemImage->setImage(Image(data));
        mItemImage->setVisible(true);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Request failed";
    }
}

void CustomImageView::select(bool select) {
}

void CustomImageView::reset(bool selected, bool activated) {
    mItemImage->setVisible(false);
}

void CustomImageView::activate(bool activate) {
}
```

**//WebServiceRequest.cpp** This class used by CustomImageView to send request for the image via internet

```
WebServiceRequest::WebServiceRequest(QString url) {
    webServiceUrl = url;
}

WebServiceRequest::~WebServiceRequest() {
}

void WebServiceRequest::getResponse() {
    QNetworkAccessManager* netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    if (!netManager) {
        qDebug() << "Unable to create QNetworkAccessManager!";
        emit complete("Unable to create QNetworkAccessManager!", false);
        return;
    }

    QUrl url(webServiceUrl);
    QNetworkRequest req(url);

    QNetworkReply* ipReply = netManager->get(req);
    connect(ipReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReply()));
}

void WebServiceRequest::onReply() {
    QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    QString response;
    bool success = false;
    if (reply) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            int available = reply->bytesAvailable();
            if (available > 0) {
                success = true;
                emit complete(reply->readAll(), success);
            }
        } else {
            response =
                    QString("Error: ") + reply->errorString()
                        + QString(" status:")
                        + reply->attribute(
                                    QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toString();
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

**//CustomImageViewProvider.cpp** This is our ListItemProvider used to customize our ListView

```
CustomImageViewProvider::CustomImageViewProvider() {
}

VisualNode * CustomImageViewProvider::createItem(ListView* list,
        const QString &type) {
    CustomImageView *myCustomImageView = new CustomImageView();
    return myCustomImageView;
}

void CustomImageViewProvider::updateItem(ListView* list,
        bb::cascades::VisualNode *listItem, const QString &type,
        const QVariantList &indexPath, const QVariant &data) {
    QVariantMap map = data.value<QVariantMap>();
    CustomImageView *myCustomImageView = static_cast<CustomImageView *>(listItem);
    qDebug() << indexPath;
    QString imagePath = map["path"].toString();
    myCustomImageView->updateItem(imagePath);
}
```

Register CustomImageView & CustomImageViewProvider with qml before creating and setting the root of main.qml in constructor. So that they are available in our qml

```
qmlRegisterType < CustomImageView > ("my.library", 1, 0, "CustomImageView");
qmlRegisterType < CustomImageViewProvider > ("my.library", 1, 0, "CustomImageViewProvider");
```

//**Path.xml** All path are stored in this file which is used as DataModel in list view

```
<root>
    <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/A_landscape_in_Peradeniya,_Sri_Lanka.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lejournaldelaphotographie.com/system/photos/54840/med_fernando-brito_lost-in-the-landscape_1-jpg.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://st.houzz.com/simgs/17713aee00b8b8b7_15-7678/modern-landscape.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000kRJbKDHBT30/s/900/720/Landscape-sunset-15.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.cashmoredesign.com/images/large/landscape-5.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/50b7d0ddb3fc4b239a0000f2_arteology-atelier-37-2_-atelier37-2_arteologie-34-528x396.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e8/Berchem,_Nicolaes_~_Landscape_with_Herdsmen_Gathering_Sticks,_early_1650s,_oil_on_panel,_private_collection,_New_York.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.taschen.com/media/images/960/teaser_mi_arch_now_landscape_top_1203301047_id_536230.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lasersandlights.com/images/medium/landscape%20bliss%20spright.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://uploads0.wikipaintings.org/images/pieter-bruegel-the-elder/landscape-with-the-flight-into-egypt-1563.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://middo.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Landscape-with-calm-river-1024x640.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/500de84928ba0d609d000038_fort-werk-aan-t-spoel-rietveld-landscape_rob6999kopierl-528x352.jpg"/>

        <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/A_landscape_in_Peradeniya,_Sri_Lanka.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lejournaldelaphotographie.com/system/photos/54840/med_fernando-brito_lost-in-the-landscape_1-jpg.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://st.houzz.com/simgs/17713aee00b8b8b7_15-7678/modern-landscape.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000kRJbKDHBT30/s/900/720/Landscape-sunset-15.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.cashmoredesign.com/images/large/landscape-5.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/50b7d0ddb3fc4b239a0000f2_arteology-atelier-37-2_-atelier37-2_arteologie-34-528x396.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e8/Berchem,_Nicolaes_~_Landscape_with_Herdsmen_Gathering_Sticks,_early_1650s,_oil_on_panel,_private_collection,_New_York.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.taschen.com/media/images/960/teaser_mi_arch_now_landscape_top_1203301047_id_536230.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lasersandlights.com/images/medium/landscape%20bliss%20spright.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://uploads0.wikipaintings.org/images/pieter-bruegel-the-elder/landscape-with-the-flight-into-egypt-1563.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://middo.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Landscape-with-calm-river-1024x640.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/500de84928ba0d609d000038_fort-werk-aan-t-spoel-rietveld-landscape_rob6999kopierl-528x352.jpg"/>

        <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/A_landscape_in_Peradeniya,_Sri_Lanka.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lejournaldelaphotographie.com/system/photos/54840/med_fernando-brito_lost-in-the-landscape_1-jpg.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://st.houzz.com/simgs/17713aee00b8b8b7_15-7678/modern-landscape.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000kRJbKDHBT30/s/900/720/Landscape-sunset-15.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.cashmoredesign.com/images/large/landscape-5.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/50b7d0ddb3fc4b239a0000f2_arteology-atelier-37-2_-atelier37-2_arteologie-34-528x396.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e8/Berchem,_Nicolaes_~_Landscape_with_Herdsmen_Gathering_Sticks,_early_1650s,_oil_on_panel,_private_collection,_New_York.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.taschen.com/media/images/960/teaser_mi_arch_now_landscape_top_1203301047_id_536230.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lasersandlights.com/images/medium/landscape%20bliss%20spright.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://uploads0.wikipaintings.org/images/pieter-bruegel-the-elder/landscape-with-the-flight-into-egypt-1563.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://middo.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Landscape-with-calm-river-1024x640.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/500de84928ba0d609d000038_fort-werk-aan-t-spoel-rietveld-landscape_rob6999kopierl-528x352.jpg"/>

        <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/A_landscape_in_Peradeniya,_Sri_Lanka.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lejournaldelaphotographie.com/system/photos/54840/med_fernando-brito_lost-in-the-landscape_1-jpg.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://st.houzz.com/simgs/17713aee00b8b8b7_15-7678/modern-landscape.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000kRJbKDHBT30/s/900/720/Landscape-sunset-15.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.cashmoredesign.com/images/large/landscape-5.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/50b7d0ddb3fc4b239a0000f2_arteology-atelier-37-2_-atelier37-2_arteologie-34-528x396.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e8/Berchem,_Nicolaes_~_Landscape_with_Herdsmen_Gathering_Sticks,_early_1650s,_oil_on_panel,_private_collection,_New_York.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://www.taschen.com/media/images/960/teaser_mi_arch_now_landscape_top_1203301047_id_536230.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://lasersandlights.com/images/medium/landscape%20bliss%20spright.jpg"/>

    <image path="http://uploads0.wikipaintings.org/images/pieter-bruegel-the-elder/landscape-with-the-flight-into-egypt-1563.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://middo.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Landscape-with-calm-river-1024x640.jpg"/>
    <image path="http://ad009cdnb.archdaily.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/500de84928ba0d609d000038_fort-werk-aan-t-spoel-rietveld-landscape_rob6999kopierl-528x352.jpg"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) in the `CustomImageViewProvider.cpp` you wrote `CustomImageView *myCustomImageView = new CustomImageView();` but CustomImageView takes a Container as parameter in its constructor right?

Comment: Object of container in CustomImageView's constructor is optional argument. Declare consturctor as **CustomImageView(Container *parent=0);** in hpp file. It will take 0 as default value.