# Set Image Source on ImageView BlackBerry

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

How to set `imageSource` on `ImageView` as url?

```
   ImageView {
               imageSource: "http://myrrix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/stackoverflow.png"
             }
```

This is not working, I can only set the image as "asset:`enter code here`///images/myimage.png" on the ImageView. How to set the source to be from URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not directly load image from web. You need to make a network request using QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager, and QNetworkReply classes & on getting reply load that QByteArray in ImageView.

```
QNetworkAccessManager* netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
if (netManager) {
    QUrl url(ImageUrl);
    QNetworkRequest networkRequest(url);
    QNetworkReply* networkReply = netManager->get(networkRequest);
    connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReply()));
}
```

& in onReply() slot you can load image:

```
void App::onReply(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Image not available or any error";
        return;
    }
    Image image = Image(reply->readAll());
    imageView->setImage(image);
}
```

Comment: I am receiving the URL to the image via JSON, and I am able to get every other object from the JSON and place it in a proper view except for the Image? For example the text goes in the Label without any problem..

Comment: Is it a list of images and other controls?

Comment: Go through this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009707/how-to-implement-grid-tiled-image-view-with-scrolling-in-bb10

Comment: Thanks sir, that link is helpful