# Cascades: ImageView with external source

Tags: imageview, blackberry-10

I need load an ImageView with a external source (http://www.example.com/some_image.jpg).

I tried with a [ImageTracker](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__imagetracker.html), but doesn't work

Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: Inbuilt support will land in next update. Till there's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622082/set-image-source-on-imageview-blackberry/14622273#14622273

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported yet - https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/roadmap/

As a workaround you can save the image to a file and load it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommed to show the image in a [WebView](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__webview.html)

Best of luck